# Jersey Client resulting in 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: java, jersey, client, media

The obvious reason for this would be not providing proper content type. But I am providing. Still i am getting Unsupported Media Type. Not sure why. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Client c = Client.create();
WebResource resource = c.resource(HOST+"/test");

Gson gson = new Gson();
Test test = new Test();
test.setTestName("TEST AUTOMATION");

resource.header("Content-Type", "Application/json");

String testStr = gson.toJson(test);
System.out.println("Request Str: "+testStr);
ClientResponse response = resource.post(ClientResponse.class, testStr);
System.out.println("POST response : "+response);
POST response : POST http://host:8888/test returned a response status of 415 Unsupported `enter code here`Media Type
```

Comment: Can you server handle json content?

Comment: You have told the request what the content-type is but does your method on the server say what type it supports? They have to match. I would expect the server side method to have an annotation like `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Comment: My Server can handle json content.

Comment: The above system.out.println prints the following Request Str: {"testName":"TEST AUTOMATION"} . I used the same request tried with DevHTTPClient. Its a rest client to rest RESTFul Service. In that I had Content-Type: application/json. Without that i am getting same 415 unsupported media type error. If i put that, i am getting 200 OK. I even tested with an Android Client Application. It worked. I dont know whats wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved it. Its really weird. Until i combine the statements as below, it didn't work. From the above program that i wrote, combine the header statement and post statement as below. Also don't forget to put charset=UTF-8.

```
ClientResponse response = resource.header("Content-Type",
            "application/json;charset=UTF-8").post(ClientResponse.class,
            testStr);
```