# JIRA REST API - 415 Unsupported Media Type error in ClientResponse

Tags: java, json, post, jersey, jira-rest-api

I am trying to send a POST request via a WebResource instance using a Jersey Client. But no matter how i specify the request headers or types, it will give me a `415 Unsupported Media Type` error. Below is my code

```
String SERVICE_URL = "http://hostIpAddress:8080/JiraUpdate/rest/createin/jira/createticket?"; // hostIpaddress is our server ip
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
System.out.println("SERVICE_URL=" + SERVICE_URL);
WebResource webResource = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(SERVICE_URL).build());
String input = "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"Invoicing\"},\"summary\":\"REST Test\",\"description\": \"Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Bug\"}}}";
ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
      .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

I have tried to set the type to `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE` as well as `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` but it doesnt change the response. I am running this code as a standalone executable JAR in a linux environment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looking at this badly formatted [example](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/consuming-restful-web-services-with-the-jersey-client-api) from Oracle - I'm pretty sure this `.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)` is overriding/undoing this `.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")` might I suggest trying one or the other,

Comment: Also, your problem looks like a duplicate of this same [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104101/jersey-client-resulting-in-415-unsupported-media-type)

Comment: Try running your request through a web debugger (eg https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and see if the service replies correctly.

Comment: @JGlass I have tried to use as you've suggested and on the linked post, but I still get the error. Also tried to remove UTF-8 but no success...

Comment: 1.  Have you tried changing it to "PUT" instead of POST? 2.  Are you sure your URL is correct?  All the examples I see for rest are like "http://example.com/rest/api/2/" or is JiraUpdate the name of your application, e.g. the context of the web app?  And as @Suenda mentioned, if you try it in your browser using fiddler or developer tools can you get it to work there and then we can backtrack to the java code?  Also, many examples use CURL, have you got it to work in CURL?

Comment: Here's also some good examples leaning more towards your URL looks strange [How to create an issue in jira via rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884960/how-to-create-an-issue-in-jira-via-rest-api)

Comment: Have tried using PUT but i get a 405 Method now allowed exception. I have also tried using another endpoint such as those like /rest/api/2/issue but they all give SSL errors. If i try to visit http://<private ip>:8080/JiraUpdate/rest/createin/jira/createticket? in a browser i get a 405 method not allowed, but any other browser test gives a page not found. I am not sure how to send a cURL request through a private linux server so cannot try this at the moment. The only way I can get it to send the request is to use a MultivaluedMap object to store my data, but i would like the JSON format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jersey Client resulting in 415 Unsupported media type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104101/jersey-client-resulting-in-415-unsupported-media-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below, based upon Vijay-Bhushan's example in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104101/jersey-client-resulting-in-415-unsupported-media-type).

Note, he mentions that UTF-8 was not needed.

```
String SERVICE_URL = "http://hostIpAddress:8080/JiraUpdate/rest/createin/jira/createticket?"; // hostIpaddress is our server ip
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
System.out.println("SERVICE_URL=" + SERVICE_URL);
WebResource webResource = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(SERVICE_URL).build());
String input = "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"Invoicing\"},\"summary\":\"REST Test\",\"description\": \"Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Bug\"}}}";

ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8").post(ClientResponse.class,input);
```

The [Jersey Client API](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.19.1/client-api.html) documentation has some great examples.

Comment: Seems like the link gives a page not found. Only a MultivaluedMap object with the json data added into it allows me to send successfully using a POST request

Comment: Corrected the link, thanks!  Sounds like you got it going, good job!